# setting up monitoring within the namespace of Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

We have a kubernetes cluster for the entire organisation. And there are namespaces for individual teams to host their projects in that cluster. The problem seems to be monitoring individual namespace. Since we have only access to our namespace we can't setup any monitoring for the PODs, containers, or the nodes on which our pods are residing. Is there any way to accomplish monitoring of only the things within the namespace without bothering the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: You can use prometheus-operator without default settings (monitoring by default: prometheus/dns/controller-manager/kubelet and etc).

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring should be provided on central level for all the basics of the cluster and more, but sure, you just need limited scope. If you deploy prometheus and configure only targets in your namespace you should be ok. Same goes for any other solutions.

For reference see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#%3Ckubernetes_sd_config%3E

```
# Optional namespace discovery. If omitted, all namespaces are used.
namespaces:
  names:
    [ - <string> ]
```

Comment: Thanks Radek for the quick reply, I tried with Prometheus SD configs, however the worker nodes are in different network zone as the kubernetes cluster is distributed across the globe so the connectivity fails. I tried with heapster and kube-state-metrics. But the pods doesn't come up as there are restricted access on the api-server, secrets, and persistent volumes.

Comment: that is to be expected. You need to decide, either you want to monitor whole cluster, where you need access to whole cluster, or you want to monitor only your namespace (pods, services etc.) then there is no reason to expect heapster or node exporter as you will be collecting metrics exposed by your software